# Add New Word From Listbox to existed Listbox in VB

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have 3 button, when 'proses' button clicked text from textbox1 will added into listBox labeled 'Kata Baru'. When '+'button clicked, the selected item from listbox 'Kata Baru' will move to listbox labeled 'Positif' as new word. As a example, 'unik' is the new word that I add to positif listbox
[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be14V.png)

**Here my code for proses button :**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim jp, jn, j As Integer
        jp = 0
        jn = 0

        teks = TextBox1.Text
        pj = Len(teks)
        For i = 1 To pj
            kata = Mid(teks, i, 1)
            If kata = " " Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(kata2)
                kata2 = ""
            Else
                kata2 = kata2 + kata
            End If
        Next
        ListBox1.Items.Add(kata2)
        jkata = ListBox1.Items.Count
        For i = 1 To jkata
            For j = 1 To jpos
                If UCase(ListBox1.Items(i - 1).ToString) = UCase(ListBox2.Items(j - 1).ToString) Then
                    jp = jp + 1
                End If

            Next
        Next

        For i = 1 To jkata
            For j = 1 To jneg
                If UCase(ListBox1.Items(i - 1).ToString) = UCase(ListBox3.Items(j - 1).ToString) Then
                    jn = jn + 1
                End If

            Next
        Next



        TextBox2.Text = jp
        TextBox3.Text = jn

    End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        kata2 = ""
        jpos = ListBox2.Items.Count
        jneg = ListBox3.Items.Count
    End Sub
```

Here's the code when + button clicked

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            ListBox3.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItems.Item(i))
        Next
    End Sub
```

My question is, how to count the word 'unik' when proses button clicked again?

Comment: Sorry but listing out requirements deson't make a question.  What exactly is the problem?  Can you update your question with a clear and concise explanation of what isn't working as expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.